# Why is my webpack bundle successfully built on host machine but is not in docker container?

Tags: javascript, docker, webpack, babeljs, babel-loader

I have a monorepo structure of my project like this:

```
babel.config.js
  a-something
  b-something
```

where I have the babel config file in the root of my project and the packages `a-something` and `b-something`.
Inside package `a-something` I have the following webpack config:

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  target: 'node',
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build')
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js?$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            rootMode: 'upward'
          }
        },
        include: [
          path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
          /node_modules\/a-/,
          /node_modules\/b-/
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Inside the package `a-something` I have the following package.json:

```
{
  "name": "a-something",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "prod:build": "webpack --config webpack.config.js",
    "prod:start": "node build/bundle.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "graphql": "^14.5.8",
    "graphql-request": "^1.8.2",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.10.1",
    "b-something": "^1.0.0",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.0",
    "sitemap": "^5.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "3.5.6",
    "@babel/polyfill": "7.7.0"
  }
}
```

My root package.json has the following dependencies:

```
"@babel/cli": "^7.5.5",
"@babel/core": "^7.5.5",
"babel-loader": "8.0.6"
```

and lastly my Dockerfile inside package `a-something` is:

```
FROM node:10.15.1
COPY ./package.json /src/package.json
ENV PORT 3000
ENV NODE_ENV production
WORKDIR /src
RUN npm install
COPY ./lerna.json /src/lerna.json
COPY ./packages/a-something/package.json /src/packages/a-something/package.json
COPY ./packages/b-something/package.json /src/packages/b-something/package.json
RUN npm run clean
COPY . /src
WORKDIR /src/packages/a-something
RUN npm run prod:build
RUN echo "FINISHED BUILDING!" 
EXPOSE ${PORT}
CMD ["npm" , "run", "prod:start"]
```

When I run `npm run prod: build` and `npm run prod: start` the bundle is built successfully, however when I build the docker (where the context is the root folder) I get the following npm error:

```
ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'babel-loader' in '/src/packages/a-something'
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! a-something@1.0.0 prod:build: `webpack --config webpack.config.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the a-something@1.0.0 prod:build script.
```

My host machine OS is macOS Mojave. Maybe the symlinks generated by Lerna are handled differently on Debian (used by node [image](https://hub.docker.com/_/node))?

---

**UPDATE:** the issue was resolved by moving all babel related npm packages from `devDependencies` to `dependencies` section of root package.json. Does anyone have an idea why this would solve the problem?

Comment: Why aren't you using lerna bootstrap ? npm install is not enough to tell Lerna to build the symlinks and enable hoisting. See https://github.com/lerna/lerna/tree/master/commands/bootstrap#readme. Personally, I've switched to yarn with lerna to get the benefits from workspaces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I mentioned in the update section of my question the solution was to move all babel related packages to `devDependencies` section of the root package.json.

But why did this help?

The problem was I set `NODE_ENV` to production in Dockerfile. [npm](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install) will not install dev dependencies if `NODE_ENV` is set to production. On the host machine I didn't have such variable. In addition another issue would've been `@babel/polyfill`, according to babel [docs](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-polyfill):

> Because this is a polyfill (which will run before your source code),
>   we need it to be a dependency, not a devDependency

According to the [docs](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-polyfill) `@babel/polyfill` is also deprecated so the better solution is to:

1. add `"babel-loader": "8.0.6"` to root package.json
2. Have the following `devDependencies` in `a-something` package.json:

```
    "devDependencies": {
        "webpack": "3.5.6",
        "core-js": "^3.4.7",
        "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.3"
      }
```

3. Place these 2 lines in the entry Javascript file at the very top:

```
import 'core-js/stable'
import 'regenerator-runtime/runtime'
```

4. Finally use this webpack config:

```
    const path = require('path')

    module.exports = {
      target: 'node',
      entry: './src/index.js',
      output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build')
      },
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.js?$/,
            use: {
              loader: 'babel-loader',
              options: {
                rootMode: 'upward',
                presets: [
                  ['@babel/preset-env', {
                    corejs: 3,
                    useBuiltIns: 'usage'
                  }]
                ]
              }
            },
            include: [
              path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
                /node_modules\/a-/,
                /node_modules\/b-/
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```